# Can you pass pre-defined values to a formio text field from a static query string

Tags: query-string, formio

I have a simple formio form set up with a basic text field component that I want to pass a value to based on a link a user will click to open the form.

I have tried passing a value with simple URL query string values.

My text field is named projectNumber. Tried passing values with something like this - https://url.com/formpage?projectNumber=project1 but it will not accept the value. I'm sure there is something simple I am missing. I have searched around quite a bit and gone through the formio documentation but have been unable to find anything related to what seems like a fairly simple scenario.

Has anyone else dealt with this situation and found a solution?